# Agrregate root, Factory and partial aggregate

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate root called `Configuration` which represent's all the options configured for a particular provisioned customer on a multi-tenant application. Since there are lot of options to be configured, the user generally follows a series of steps (through wizards) and then sometimes wants to partially save the data to be completed later (may be next day).

I am familiar with the `Factory` concept and one of its rule is **not** to enabled creation of partial aggregate objects if they fail the invariant rules.

My question is how to solve the **partial object** use-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent an entity being in a incomplete state, and if you are storing that partially-filled entity just for storing the intermediate request (instead of treating it as one entity), you may have a separate entity to represent the "Creation Request".  It makes sense to me that Creation Request (which you can treat that as a factory or input to a factory, in another aspect) can be partially filled and persisted, and upon complete, be used to create the actual entity you want.

Comment: +1. Essentially, this is the builder pattern. Builders are not usually persistent, but in this case, they could be.

Comment: Whether it is a Builder or other creational pattern it depends on how OP is going to design it  :)  At least we know that piece of class is some kind of factory.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your requirement suggests to me that the aggregate is allowed to exist with only a partial amount of data set, therefore I do not see a problem? There is no invariant that says "the aggregate is only considered valid once all steps have be completed", in fact quite the opposite, it seems.